# SQL Server 2008: hide any row associate with original ticket when Status is cancel

Tags: sql-server-2008

How can I say to hide any "original ticket" when the column `status` is `Cancel`?

```
 Date    Date Stamp Original Ticket  Trade Number  Status
 ----    ---------- ---------------  ------------  ------
 01 jan    01 jan      123                130      Modify
 01 jan    02 jan      123                140      Cancel
 03 jan    03 jan      145                150      Modify
 04 jan    04 jan      160                200      Cancel
 05 jav    05 jan      210                220             ( empty because some trades are not modify)
```

The result: I expect to see  the row with original ticket 145 and 210, and not the original ticket 123 and 160

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT z.[Original Ticket], z.[Modify], z.[Cancel]
FROM 
(
    SELECT  x.ColA, x.[Original Ticket], x.[Status] -- Where ColA is PK or a mandatory (NOT NULL) column
    FROM    dbo.MyTable x
) y
PIVOT( COUNT(y.ID) FOR y.[Status] IN ([Modify], [Cancel]) ) z
WHERE z.[Modify] > 0 AND z.[Cancel] = 0
```

Example:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
    SELECT 1, 123, 'Modify'
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2, 123, 'Cancel'
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 3, 145, 'Modify'
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 4, 200, 'Cancel'
) y(ColA, [Original Ticket], [Status]) 
PIVOT( COUNT(y.ColA) FOR y.[Status] IN ([Modify], [Cancel]) ) z
WHERE z.[Modify] > 0 AND z.[Cancel] = 0

/*
Output:
Original Ticket Modify      Cancel
--------------- ----------- -----------
145             1           0
*/
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Bogdan. It's works but i have do have null because some transactions are not modify.

Comment: @Hicham: Except COUNT(*), [aggregate functions ignore null values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)#Aggregate_functions).

Comment: Tks Bodgan. So if i use COUNT(*), every Status Null will appear?

Comment: i try z.[''] in the select and on the pivot: PIVOT( COUNT(y.ID) FOR y.[Status] IN ([Modify], [Cancel]), [''] ) z, and on the where : WHERE z.[Modify]= 1 AND z.[Cancel] = 0 AND z.[''] = 2.... But it's not working

Comment: j'essaie cette requête:                                         select date,datestamp,original_ticket,trade_number,status
from
(
 select *,row_number() over(partition by original_ticket order by datestamp desc) as rn
 from #temp
) tt
where rn=1 and isnull(status,'')<>'cancel'                                Result: Strange, when i excute the query, sometimes work and sometimes not. It's not regular. Do you know why?

Comment: [0] There are other statuses than `Modify` and `Cancel` ? [1] Maybe the problem is what rows are inserted into `#temp` table. [2] What do you mean by `sometimes work and sometimes not. It's not regular` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE [status] <> 'cancel'
```

Comment: Tks Ali. without the cancel, i still have the original ticket 123